# Query for keychain keys return nil

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm using the [flutter secure storage package](https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/blob/develop/flutter_secure_storage/ios/Classes/FlutterSecureStorage.swift) that uses iOS keychain to store values. I also added a NotificationServiceExtension and need to access a key stored by the package. This is the function used to access the key.

```
func getKeychainValue(forKey key: String) -> String? {
    let query: [String: Any] = [
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrAccount as String: key,
        kSecReturnData as String: true,
        kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne
    ]

    var item: CFTypeRef?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &item)
    if status == errSecSuccess, let data = item as? Data, let value = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        return value
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The issue is that this function keeps returning nil. Is there configuration needed i.e keychain sharing to enable the use of the keys stored by the package? The package doesn't seem to specify any specific keychain groups.

Comment: The only real difference between your code and the code I use is that I also include a value for `kSecAttrService` in the query dictionary.